# javascript function not called in $(document).ready

Tags: javascript, jquery

How come my javascript function doesn't get called if I have it inside a document.ready call.

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    //doesn't get called
    function Test() {
        //do something
    }
}

///does get called
function Test() {
}
```

Comment: Called **from where**?

Comment: called from a onchange event in my html element

Comment: If you put the function inside the on ready,  it will not be in scope.

Comment: *facepalm*.     The function isn't called.

Comment: Functions declared inside other functions are **private** and not visible outside. That's the answer to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> called from a onchange event in my html element

I assume that means you have something like

```
<input onchange="Test()" />
```

in your HTML.

In that case the answer is: Because of [**scope**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Variable_scope).

Inline event handlers are evaluated in *global* scope. In your first example, `Test` is not defined in global scope, it is defined inside the function you pass to `$(document).ready`. Hence the inline event handler cannot find the function.

Here is a simplified example:

```
function ready() {
    function Test() { }
}

ready();
Test(); // ReferenceError because Test is not defined in this scope
```

---

**Note** that there is no reason to put function definitions inside a `$(document).ready` callback, except for explicitly not putting them in global scope.

Answer (score 0):

Two reasons:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    //doesn't get called
    function Test() {
        //do something
        console.log('test called');
    }

    Test();
}
                 );
```

You were missing the last outer paren (last line above), and you were not calling the function you defined.

http://jsfiddle.net/fepy8239/

Comment: He updated his question to include that the function is being called from an element's `onchange` event

Answer (score 0):

All you're doing in your first example is defining the function. You're not invoking it.  If you change it as follows, you're now defining *and* invoking it:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    //does get called
    (function Test() {
        //do something
    })();
});
```

(I assume the missing outer parenthesis at the end was a typo in posting the question, but I'll point it out just in case...)

Comment: He updated his question to include that the function is being called from an element's `onchange` event

Answer (score 0):

The question you ask is equal to this:

```
function start() {

 function test() { 
  thisWontWork(); 

 }

}

start();
```

If you call/start a function it doesn't mean that the functions in there will start too. A rookie mistake which shouldn't be repeated. Keep it in mind!